# selenium and Java - finding element without id/name

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have following piece of html code:

```
<td>
<p>
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="collapseYearByBrand('XY')" type="button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
XYZ
</button>
</p>
2018
</td>
```

How can I find the button in Selenium Firefox webdriver (java)?
There is no id or name so I expect a working solution would be to find it by xpath or cssSelector.

I am new in java. I would be very grateful for any advice.

Comment: why not add an id?

Comment: @Stultuske It's not a good assumption to make that most script writers have the ability to add ids or otherwise change the HTML of the site they are working on.

Comment: @JeffC neither is it a good assumption that Selenium tests are/should be written by a person not writing/maintaining the code. if pburgr can't add id's, he had about 5 hours to share that. In one of the comments on an answer, he replied he'll ask the author to add in id's, so I guess that fixes that problem

Answer (score 1):

By cssSelector - `driver.findElement(By.className("btn.btn-default"))`

By xPath - `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/p/button"))`

Comment: In that case, you need to know the index of the button you are interested in and do something like this

driver.findElements(By.className("btn.btn-default")).get(INDEX_OF_YOUR_BUTTON);

Comment: there are more such buttons in the form, sorry I din`t mentioned it

Comment: Like i mentioned in the previous comment, you can either get the index of the button and get it by className or you have to construct the xPath which in your case would not be readable solution

Comment: I asked the author for the indexes, he will add ids to all these butons and make my life bit easier :-)

Comment: Thats much better! Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

> I expect a working solution would be to find it by xpath or cssSelector.

You are right in your assumption, use cssSelector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-default"));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18497963)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Using cssSelector is the answer to the question "How can I find the button in Selenium Firefox webdriver (java)?". I will remove the "What exactly is your problem?" from my answer.

Comment: @MaxVollmer it's 'an' answer, and depending on the entire code of the user, it might be the answer. problem is, we have no way of telling whether there are other buttons in his code

Comment: @Stultuske The question was how to find the button, given the provided HTML, not how to find any button, given any HTML. I can update my answer when OP updates their question, but with the given information my answer does answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody facing same issue, relative xpath can be used.

```
(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-default')]")
```

Just make always sure, there are no other WebElements fitting on the relative xpath. Otherwise find for all WebElements and get the desired one by index.